# active class lost due to page reload

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have two tabs on my page

1. Tabular
2. Graphical

My page showing two forms of same data as mentioned above, by default it is showing graphical form.

My code for tabs are:

```html
<form method="get">
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="active" ><a href="todayfiletype1.php?graph=1" >Graphical View</a></li>
         <li ><a href="todayfiletype1.php?graph=2">Tabular View</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

When I click on one of tab I want to execute below code as per the query string I passed with hyperlink, however page gets reloaded active class does not change with change in tabs

```
if(isset($_GET['graph']))
{
$opt=$_GET['graph'];
}
else
$opt=1;

if($opt==1)
{
//code related to graphical tab
}
else
{
//code related to tabular tab
}
```

Please suggest me how can I get active class as per click..Currently it is changing but lost due to page reload.

Jquery code used to switch active class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("li").click(function(event) {
          //event.preventDefault();
          if ($("li").hasClass('active')) {
               $("li").removeClass('active');
          }
          $(this).addClass('active');
     });
});
```

Comment: You already get the selected graph into the `$opt` variable. Use it to select the right tab. It's hard to go into detail, since your code snippet contains a lot of 'noise'. Could you remove all the code that is related of drawing the graphs on the tabs, so there are just two plain tabs to switch between?

Comment: I am getting the right graph but active class is not changing accordingly. due to page reload active class changes are lost .

Comment: @Rajendra Where in the above code do you set the active class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the class to the correct element, based on the value of the `$opt` variable:

```
<form method="get">
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li<?php echo ($opt==1)?' class="active"':'';?>><a href="todayfiletype1.php?graph=1" >Graphical View</a></li>
          <li<?php echo ($opt==2)?' class="active"':'';?>><a href="todayfiletype1.php?graph=2">Tabular View</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: @Rajendra Great, glad i could help. Also note there was a small typo in my answer - i had `($opt==1)` twice, when of course the second line should be `($opt==2)`. I have edited to show this

Comment: @Rajendra Yes i thought so, but made the edit for future visitors